# distinguishing dependencies and devDependencies in Next.js

Tags: webpack, dependencies, package.json

Does distinguishing `dependencies` and `devDependencies` have any advantages?

As far as I know, next.js goes through a `tree-shaking` process that removes all unused code and dependencies from the actual live application during the build process. To be precise, during the bundling process using `webpack`. So whether I install some packages to `devDependencies` or `dependencies`, all unused packages are not going to be bundled anyway. Is there any advantage to actually distinguishing these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing techically, but one thing practically.

Unless you run `npm intsall --production`, the build output will be exactly same. The only advantage is that people can easily know that which packages are used(imported) in the project, and which are not(or are only used for dev).

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14000